# Excel Macro for checkbox if true

Tags: vba, excel

i need a macro or a line to add to my code for when the checkbox is true or "Checked" i need it to copy the content of a specific cell into another in a  sheet in the same workbook what i was able to get to is this code

```
Sub macro2()
Range("A1:C4").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("sheet2").Select
Range("A1:C4").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

but as you can see it only gets me to get this range to be copied and pasted once i have checked the box what i need is to copy it when checked and maybe not to let it get m to the cell in sheet2 to allow multiple selections to be pasted in some specified cells i know i have the code sheet2.select but i honestly don't know any other coding and i need to put that kind of coding for over hundred cells so do appreciate your assistance with this if anybody can please am dying here

Answer (score 0):

```
 If CheckBox1.Value = True Then 
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C4").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C4").Value 
 End if
```